# Recursion with Palindrome wrong result in boolean

Tags: java, loops, recursion, boolean

im trying to check if a String is a palindrome, i converted the String to an CharArray and cleaned it up by removing all special characters.

**Now what i did:**
If the first and last element of words do not match it terminates, if not it deletes element 0 & n and starts the method again.

If I run following words, all are correct except the first one and i don't understand why.

palin("Odsadao"); ==> Result : TRUE ; Expected: FALSE 
palin("Acce"); ==> Result : FALSE ; Expected: FALSE 
palin("civic"); ==> Result : TRUE ; Expected: TRUE 
palin("Malaalam"); ==> Result : TRUE ; Expected: TRUE 
palin("Flee to me, remote elf."); ==> Result : TRUE ; Expected: TRUE 
palin("Genius, this is awesome!"); ==> Result : FALSE ; Expected: FALSE

```
 public static boolean palin(String text){
    
     char[] words = text.toCharArray(); 
     int wordlength = text.length();

     if (words[0] != words[wordlength-1])
     {
        return false;
     }
    
     else 
     { 
        if (wordlength <= 2) 
        {
          return true;
        }
    
        else {
          text = text.substring(1,text.length()-1); // Delete index 0 & n
          palin(text); //recursion with substring 
          }
      }
            
     return true;
  }
```

If I print the steps, all seems fine, he's comparing the right elements but the result is still wrong
println(text) ==> Odsadao 
println(words[0] + "" words[length-1] ==> O & O 
println(text) == >DSADA 
println(words[0] + "" words[length-1] ==> D & A 
Palindrom? true

Comment: `Malaylam` and `Acce` should return `false` as well.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `palin(text); //recursion with substring `, what do you expect to happen immediately after the recursive call returns? Hint: what if, instead of making a recursive call to `palin`, you called someone else's `palin2` which also just happened to solve the palindrome detection problem in a different way? Does that make the problem clear?

Comment: Is all this a requirement? I think it's just easier to do: `boolean isPalindrome = myString.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\s+", "").equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(myString).reverse().toString().replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\s+", ""));`.

Comment: yes, its a requirement for homework

Comment: @QBrute you're right, i changed my text.thx

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the result of the recursive call.

It should be:

```
public static boolean palin(String text)
{
    char[] words = text.toCharArray(); 
    int wordlength = text.length();

    if (words[0] != words[wordlength-1]) {
        return false;
    } else  { 
        if (wordlength <= 2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            text = text.substring(1,text.length()-1); // Delete index 0 & n
            System.out.println (text);
            return palin(text); //recursion with substring 
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. you have to return `palin(text)`.

Otherwise your code will always return true when the first and last characters are equal.

BTW, `palin("Odsadao")` returns `false` in your implementation, as expected, since `'O' != 'o'`. However, if you try `palin("odsadao")`, it incorrectly returns `true`.

Comment: follow up question,  how can I count the execution of the recursion now? 
I need to print how often the return palin(text) is executed and how often the test runs

Comment: @EddiOne one way is to increment some static variable each time palin is entered.